# Is temperature everywhere continuous?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

Is temperature everywhere continuous or can there exist discontinuities?
That is, if we take temperature as a function of position, will there be any jumps or just steep increases/decreases?

An application: if we have a room that is 80°C and a room that is 20°C, can we apply the Intermediate Value Theorem to state that there is a point (or surface) between the two rooms that has a temperature of exactly 50°C?

This question was motivated by the famous theorem that there always exist two points diametrically opposite each other on the globe that have the same temperature. Is this statement valid to make based on the continuity of temperature?

Comment: This seems like 3 questions

Comment: If system are mostly locally in equilibrium (no dynamics) and conditions are so that there are no abrupt boundary conditions then maybe you can consider a temperature field that is continuous. In the most general case temperature is not defined very well because most systems with different temperatures are usually in a larger system that is out-of-equilibrium and it is not always possible to define temperature.

Comment: Ignoring the subtleties with even defining local temperature, you're stating a needlessly weak version. The famous theorem tells us that there are diametrically opposite points with the same temperature *and pressure*.

Comment: Naively I'm thinking that even if there are discontinuities, the heat equation dictates that any discontinuity would instantaneously get smoothened out, but perhaps there is some phenomena that I am not aware of that gets around my naive reasoning.

Comment: Here's what "continuous" means in physics: "The primary difference, though, between discrete and continuous data is that discrete data is a finite value that can be counted whereas continuous data has an infinite number of possible values that can be measured." It is an antonym of "discrete". As stated this question is nonsensical and belongs in philosophy, not physics.

Comment: Is matter continuous?

Comment: Temperature is not even necessarily defined at all points in space. It certainly isn't continuous at the points where it isn't defined.

Comment: @fertilizerspike - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There can be a brief discontinuity in temperature if heat is instantaneously applied to a surface.  Also, for shock phenomena the temperature (and pressure) can be essentially discontinuous at the shock front, the interface of the shocked and unshocked material.